# Word to call a person that works in the registration counter

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for the word to call a person that works in the registration counter for an audition. Their job scopes are to confirm the auditees' attendance, double check if they need special requirements from the organiser for the audition. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I guess you'd call her the *registrar*. But no one does.  I've never been behind the counter, but from the other side, we usually just call them "the check-in lady" or "front-desk guy", etc.

Comment: An audition?  LIke the one for actors trying out for a role?

Comment: Please be aware that when talking of people we do not use the relative pronoun *that*. We would use *who*. So: *I'm looking for the word to call a person **who** works in the registration department*.

Comment: @WS2 in the USA *that*, including the relative pronoun *that*,  is commonly used for persons. And the first example sentence in ODO (Br & World English) is *‘the woman that owns the place’*

Comment: @WS2 what I'm wondering about are why are people saying *in the registration counter* or *on the counter* (in my AmE understanding, the former would mean *inside* and the latter *on top of* the counter).  But some folks in NYC and elsewhere say *on line* instead of *in line*, which represents more widespread usage. I would have to say *at the counter*.

Comment: @Clare I would agree with you entirely about "on" and "in the registration counter". I would use neither, preferring "at" or "behind the counter". We, in Britain, particularly use "behind" when talking about "the bar". *I can't buy a drink, there's no one behind the bar*. As regards "that" versus "who", yes, I have to agree, it works in your example, though it doesn't work for me in the OP's example. I'm not sure why. I take your point, but will not delete my comment, as it seems to have attracted support from at least one person.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what sort of audition you're going to but I worked for a casting director for commercials and films and I was that person.

My official title was "assistant" as in "casting assistant". Quite often, we'd give this job to our interns, too...

For us, there was no one "right" name for this person as it could likely be anyone within the casting company. Also remember that this person likely does much more than only check people in and make sure they have their headshots and scripts etc... for me, I also helped create the schedules, interacted with agents to book or request talent to attend casting calls, wrote press releases... my duties depended on the day of the week and whether we held a casting session that day.

If you really need to call them something, call them an "assistant". Yes, it's generic but, even for our interns, the term fits.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term *gatekeeper* is fitting.

Mitigating against the use of that term, however, is that the person of whom you speak does not necessarily *control* who does or does not get into the audition, as a true gatekeeper would, but rather 1) puts a checkmark next to the registrant's name when he or she shows up, and 2) determines if the registrant has any special needs prior to being auditioned.

Perhaps, then, the word *screener* would be more apropos, or perhaps even *greeter* and/or *attendance taker*.

Take your pick!

Answer (score 1):

**Registration hostess** may fit.

> The roles of a host & hostess can include: meet & greet, registration,
>   cloakroom, providing venue/directional information, serving beverages
>   and canapés and ensuring guests are well looked after.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at a counter who greets you, writes down that you have arrived and asks if you need any help sounds like a **[receptionist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/receptionist)** to me:

> a person employed to receive and assist callers, clients, etc., as in an office.

Answer (score -1):

The word I generally use to describe anyone who works at a counter is "attendant."

Comment: On the counter? Do you mean on top of the counter or something else? Because I would have to say *at the counter*. But maybe *on the counter*, as in *on counter duty* is said by others...

Comment: Welcome to English.SE and thank you for your input!  I took the liberty of editing your post to clarify its meaning.